# Doing left outer join with a local sequence in Linq To Sql

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, left-join

I need to bypass the "Local sequence cannot be used in Linq To Sql" limitation, doing a left-outer join. The left-outer join should return an `IQueryable<T>`.

Here's an example code:

```
public IQueryable<MyContainer> LeftOuter(IQueryable<MyContainer> query, List<Guid> myIds)
{
    var leftOuterQuery =
                        from container in query
   /* Exception --> */  from id in myIds.Where(myId => container.ContainerId == myId).DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new { Container = container, Id = id };

    return leftOuterQuery.Where(joined => joined.Container.ContainerId == null)
                         .Select(joined => joined.Container);    
}
```

Comment: Did you try`from container in query.ToList()`?

Comment: I don't want to materialize the records (Can cause an OutOfMemory exception).

Comment: I reckon "from id in myIds.Where" is the bit that locks it to memory - are you trying to look for ids contained in myIds? Wouldn't that be something like query.Where(myIds.Contains(container.ContainerId))? Could you describe what you want to achieve with a small data set?

Comment: @Adam Benson, the function's returned query object should be a filtered version of the passed-in query object. Suppose calling ToList on the passed query returns 10k objects, and suppose that myIds contains the ids of the first 1k objects, then calling ToList on the returned query should returns the other 9k objects.

Comment: Note that I can do `query.Where(!myIds.Contains(container.ContainerId))` but I think it's not efficient and thus prefer a left join and call where-select, as in the code above

Comment: I wouldn't assume it isn't efficient without checking the SQL generated. `Contains` is supported by LINQ to SQL and generally uses `IN` in SQL - not sure how you can be more efficient server side without creating a temp table.